# How are artifacts destroyed?

Tags: dnd-5e, artifacts

I think my question is fairly straightforward - how does one destroy an artifact?

The only reference I have been able to find is the following passage from the DMG page 140 under 'Magic Item Resilience':

> Most magic items are objects of extraordinary artisanship. Thanks to a combination of careful crafting and magical reinforcement, a magic item is at least as durable as a nonmagical item of its kind. Most magic items, other than potions and scrolls, have resistance to all damage. **Artifacts are practically indestructible, requiring extraordinary measures to destroy.**

**What would be an 'extraordinary measure' sufficient to destroy an artifact?**

I was able to find [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/4j0mjn/5e_how_to_destroy_an_artifact/) discussing the topic, but the thread only lists examples from previous versions of DnD, including:

> 1. Melt it down in the fiery furnace, pit, mountain, forge, crucible or kiln in which it was created.
> 2. Drop it into or bury it beneath (1) the Well of Time, (2) the Abyss, (3) the Earth Wound, (4) Adonais' Deep, (5) the Spring of Eternity, (6) Marion's Trench, (7) the Living Stone, (8) Mountain of Thunder, (9) 100 adult red dragon skulls, (10) the Tree of the Universe.
> 3. Cause it to be devoured by (1) Cerebus, (2) a Lernaean Hydra, (3) a Titan, (4) an ancient Dragon Turtle.
> 4. Cause it to be broken against/by or crushed by (1) talos a triple iron golem, (2) the Gates of Hell, (3) the Cornerstone of the World, (4) Artur's Dolmen, (5) the Juggernaut of the Endless Labyrinth, (6) the heel of a god, (7) the Clashing Rocks, (8) the foot of a humble ant.
> 5. Expose it to the penetrating light and flame of (1) the Ray of Eternal Shrinking, (2) the Sun, (3) Truth: that which is pure will become Light, that which is impure will surely wither.
> 6. Cause it to be steeped in either the encephalic fluids of the brain of Bahamut (the platinum dragon), or in the black and foul blood from the heart of tiamat the chromatic dragon.
> 7. Cause it to be seared by the odious flames of Geryon's destroyed soul or disintegrated in the putrid ichor of Juiblex's deliquescing flesh.
> 8. Sprinkle it with/baptize it in the (1) Well of Life, (2) River Styx, (3) River of Flame, (4) River Lethe (the river of forgetfulness).

I am looking specifically for 5e examples from WotC source books or similarly reliable sources (eg Jeremy Crawford tweets) regarding how to destroy artifacts.

If no such clarifications exist for 5e then I would accept an answer that clarifies this to be the case.

Comment: Almost every artifact has a unique way of destroying it. Do you have a specific artifact you are asking about?

Comment: @DavidCoffron I am not looking for a specific artifact, just asking if there are general rules which discuss the destruction of artifacts

Comment: Do you have access to the DMG?

Comment: @korvinstarmast I do not

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Erm, I don't see how the DMG doesn't solve your problem. The DMG has a Destroying an Artifact section, where it explains how it works, p. 221.

> An artifact must be destroyed in some special way.
>   Otherwise, it is impervious to damage.
>   **Each artifact has a weakness by which its creation
>   can be undone**. Learning this weakness might require
>   extensive research or the successful completion of a
>   quest. **The DM decides how a particular artifact can be
>   destroyed**. Some suggestions are provided here:
>
> - The artifact must be melted down in the volcano,
>     forge, or crucible in which it was created.
> - The artifact must be dropped into the River Styx.
> - The artifact must be swallowed and digested by the
>     tarrasque or some other ancient creature.
> - The artifact must be bathed in the blood of a god
>     or an angel.
> - The artifact must be struck and shattered by a special
>     weapon crafted for that purpose.
> - The artifact must be pulverized between the titanic
>     gears of Mechanus.
> - The artifact must be returned to its creator, who can
>     destroy it by touch.

More specifically, each described artifact has a specific way described as to how to destroy it. For example, the Axe of the Dwarvish Lords

> ***Destroying the Axe.*** The only way to destroy the
>   axe is to melt it down in the Earthheart Forge, where
>   it was created. It must remain in the burning forge for
>   fifty years before it finally succumbs to the fire and
>   is consumed.

Comment: We had almost literally the same format for our answers. Bravo

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I don't know why a Google search didn't just return this section of the DMG. I'll leave the question open for another little while to see if any other answers trickle in with any clarifications on the above

Answer (score 15):

### Every Artifact is Different

The Dungeon Master's Guide provides some examples in the [Destroying Artifacts section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/sentient-magic-items-artifacts#Artifacts), but beyond that it is a case by case basis.

> An artifact must be destroyed in some special way. Otherwise, it is impervious to damage.
>
> ... The DM decides how a particular artifact can be destroyed. Some suggestions are provided here:
>
> - The artifact must be melted down in the volcano, forge, or crucible in which it was created.
> - The artifact must be dropped into the River Styx.
> - The artifact must be swallowed and digested by the tarrasque or some other ancient creature.
> - The artifact must be bathed in the blood of a god or an angel.
> - The artifact must be struck and shattered by a special weapon crafted for that purpose.
> - The artifact must be pulverized between the titanic gears of Mechanus.
> - The artifact must be returned to its creator, who can destroy it by touch.

Take the Sword of Kas for example. It's description includes:

> ***Destroying the Sword.*** A creature attuned to both the *Eye of Vecna* and the *Hand of Vecna* can use the *wish* property of those combined artifacts to unmake the *Sword of Kas*.

Every official artifact has a similar section for it's method of destruction.

Comment: Old module from back in the day... Throne of Bloodstone you had to destroy the Wand of Orcus, which required you to travel to the first layer of Hell and defeat Tiamat and her consorts. After which you had to plunge the wand into her opened heart. Fun times had by all :(